# React Unit Testing State Updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm in the middle of trying to get as close to 100% unit test coverage with my React application as possible, however I'm in a bit of a pickle with trying to get test coverage on the `useAsync` hook. I took the following code from [use react hooks](https://usehooks.com/useAsync/):

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const useAsync = (asyncFunction, immediate = true) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('idle');
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  // The execute function wraps asyncFunction and
  // handles setting state for pending, value, and error.
  // useCallback ensures the below useEffect is not called
  // on every render, but only if asyncFunction changes.
  const execute = useCallback(() => {
    setStatus('pending');
    setValue(null);
    setError(null);

    return asyncFunction()
      .then(response => {
        setValue(response);
        setStatus('success');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setError(error);
        setStatus('error');
      });
  }, [asyncFunction]);

  // Call execute if we want to fire it right away.
  // Otherwise execute can be called later, such as
  // in an onClick handler.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (immediate) {
      execute();
    }
  }, [execute, immediate]);

  return { execute, status, value, error };
};
```

And it works fine. I've not done anything funky or included any additional testing libraries/dependencies on top of what you'd get when you run `npx create-react-app ...`.

Because I couldn't find a suitable solution for my team to test react hooks without relying on additional dependencies, i.e. [react-hooks-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library), I created a mock component to wrap the hook in, then I just test the different possible states like so:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useAsync } from "../../hooks";

afterEach(cleanup);

const MockComponent = (props) => {
  const { status } = useAsync(props.callback, props.immediate);
  return <p id="test">{status}</p>
};

const defaultCallback = () => {
  new Promise((resolve) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Success!");
    }, 1000)
  });
};

// Example of a test that runs fine, no problem at all!
test("useAsync gets to a pending state", () => {
  const { container } = render(<MockComponent callback={defaultCallback} immediate={true} />
  const pTag = container.querySelector("p#test");
  expect(pTag.textContent).toBe("idle");
});

// This is where I get my issue...
test("useAsync gets to a success state", (done) => {
  const { container } = render(<MockComponent callback={defaultCallback} immediate={true} />
  const pTag = container.querySelector("p#test");
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(pTag.textContent).toBe("success");
    done();
  }, 2000);
});

// Some other tests...
```

When I run these two tests that I've included above, they actually run fine and if I look at the code coverage report(s) that are generated, it's 100% coverage. In the console, though, when running these tests, when I run the second one, I get the following error and I'm not sure how to resolve it. I have tried to wrap the entire body of the test in `act`, but that made no difference, so I'm not entirely sure what the best approach may be here.

Here's the console output:

```
console.error
 Warning: An update to MockComponent inside a tests was not wrapped in act(...).

 When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

 act(() => {
   /* fire events that update state */
 });
 /* assert on the output */

 This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act 
  at MockComponent....
```

As I've said, I've tried to wrap my entire test(s) with an act, but I've had no luck there. What I have found interesting is that in the console output, when it apparently errors, it also highlights this snippet of the hook:

```js
      .then(response => {
        setValue(response);
        // ^
        setStatus('success');
        // ^
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setError(error);
```

Should I perhaps ignore this issue? After all when all of my tests are run, no tests/test suite fails or anything.

Comment: @Ahmad that's all part of the warning in the console.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe, that's why I had it there. :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe my apologies, I thought it's a paragraph

Comment: @AhmadAlfy I appreciate that you were looking through the question though, I know it's quite a 'bulky' question in all fairness! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after much tinkering & googling, I found an answer to my problem, thankfully it's relatively straightforward!  - The short answer being the use of `waitFor`.

I made a *couple* of other modifications, i.e. assigned the timeout delay to a variable called `timeout`, but nothing major.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useAsync } from "../../hooks";

afterEach(cleanup);

let timeout = 1000;

beforeEach(() => {
  timeout = 1000
});

const MockComponent = (props) => {
  const { status } = useAsync(props.callback, props.immediate);
  return <p id="test">{status}</p>
};

const defaultCallback = () => {
  new Promise((resolve) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Success!");
    }, timeout)
  });
};

// Example of a test that runs fine, no problem at all!
test("useAsync gets to a pending state", () => {
  const { container } = render(<MockComponent callback={defaultCallback} immediate={true} />
  const pTag = container.querySelector("p#test");
  expect(pTag.textContent).toBe("idle");
});

// This now works! :D 
test("useAsync gets to a success state", async () => {
  timeout = 0;
  const { container } = render(<MockComponent callback={defaultCallback} immediate={true} />
  const pTag = container.querySelector("p#test");
  expect(pTag).toBeInTheDocument();
  
  // Yes!
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(pTag.textContent).toBe("success");
  });
});

// Some other tests...
```